# Using express & Node, how can I send JSON in HTTP GET params?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using express and want to pass a JSON to my HTTP GET route function:
`app.get('/myRoute/:data', (req, res) => {}`

I can't do it using HTTP POST so I must be able to pass a JSON in the url.

Can it be done?

Comment: Just `JSON.stringify()` to convert JSON to string, then `JSON.parse()` ton convert back to JSON :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` and `encodeURI` to make your JSON url friendly like this:
`encodeURI(JSON.stringify({a: 'b'}))`

Then just call your GET function with the result:

`/myRoute/%7B%22a%22:%22b%22%7D`

You can get the passed JSON in your function by parsing it:

```
app.get('/myRoute/:data', (req, res) => {
    const parsedJSONFromParam = JSON.parse(unescape(req.params.data));
  });
```

Comment: question and answer alone at the same minute? :D

Comment: [Almost like there is a checkbox for that](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I know but it's just pretty "interesting" that the answer happened at the same minute of the question :)

Comment: He probably just ran into the issue and wanted to document it for others